# How to include a custom font in ionic 3?

Tags: ionic-framework, fonts, ionic3

Custom Font related question.
It's the first time that I try to use a custom font inside the App but I have a lot of problems..

Example: I want to use this google font https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Special+Elite

I've downloaded this font and put it into /assets/fonts

In **variables.scss** I added the code:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'SpecialElite-Regular';
  src:  url('../assets/fonts/SpecialElite-Regular.ttf') format('ttf');
  font-weight: 800;
  font-style: regular;
}
```

and I tried to apply this font to all the code:
**app.scss**

```
*{
font-family: "SpecialElite" !important;
}
```

But the font isn't shown (not in browser, not in app).

How can I use a custom font?

---

## SOLVED:

I've included different types of font's..

**variables.scss**

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'SpecialElite-Regular';
  src:  url( $font-path + '/SpecialElite-Regular/SpecialElite-Regular.ttf') format('ttf'), 
        url( $font-path + '/SpecialElite-Regular/SpecialElite-Regular.eot') format('eot'),
        url( $font-path + '/SpecialElite-Regular/SpecialElite-Regular.svg') format('svg'),
        url( $font-path + '/SpecialElite-Regular/SpecialElite-Regular.woff') format('woff'),
        url( $font-path + '/SpecialElite-Regular/SpecialElite-Regular.woff2') format('woff2');
}
```

**where I want to use my font**

```
font-family: 'SpecialElite-Regular' !important;
```

Comment: Please move your solution to an answer of its own, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've included different types of fonts.

**variables.scss**

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'SpecialElite-Regular';
  src:  url( $font-path + '/SpecialElite-Regular/SpecialElite-Regular.ttf') format('ttf'), 
        url( $font-path + '/SpecialElite-Regular/SpecialElite-Regular.eot') format('eot'),
        url( $font-path + '/SpecialElite-Regular/SpecialElite-Regular.svg') format('svg'),
        url( $font-path + '/SpecialElite-Regular/SpecialElite-Regular.woff') format('woff'),
        url( $font-path + '/SpecialElite-Regular/SpecialElite-Regular.woff2') format('woff2');
}
```

**where I want to use my font**

```
font-family: 'SpecialElite-Regular' !important;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it is because you are trying to use this font under a different name than that you gave to it :

```
*{
font-family: "SpecialElite-Regular" !important;
}
```

should do the trick